# Is there a way to utilize FFMpeg in .NET MAUI for editing videos?

Tags: .net, ffmpeg, maui

I've tried to find all the information I can about utilizing FFMpeg inside of .NET MAUI (iOS & Android) to easily edit videos on the device, but it seems like there is very little information on how to accomplish this.

FFMpeg is widely used in the video industry, and I believe a FFMpeg plugin for .NET MAUI would be hugely beneficial to the MAUI community.

It looks like you can use dependency injection to get interfaces for each OS with their own binaries, but I personally haven't been able to get this to work.